# Xfinium: How to generate PDF with landscape orientation

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin

I am using Xfinium pdf for the Xamarin project. Pdf is being generated in Portrait mode. How can I change the orientation of the pdf to Landscape?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, In order for us to help you, we need to see what you have tried/done so far. Would you be able to add a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a page with a Width larger than Height:

   ```
   PdfFixedDocument doc = new PdfFixedDocument();
   PdfPage page = doc.Pages.Add();
   // Create a landscape letter page
   page.Width = 792;
   page.Height = 612;
   ```
2. Create a portrait page and rotate it:

   ```
   PdfFixedDocument doc = new PdfFixedDocument();
   // Default page is portrait letter
   PdfPage page = doc.Pages.Add();
   // Create a landscape letter page
   page.Rotation = 90;
   ```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops the XFINIUM.PDF library.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I am using PdfFlowDocument and the same solution worked using PdfFlowDocumentDefaults.

Comment: @Harvinder - yes, for flow documents the PdfFlowDocumentDefaults is the solution.